# Angular form field validation after field exit and in the field

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a function that verify if a serial number exist on my database

```
serialVerification(sn: string){
    const serial = sn;
    this.http.get<any>(`http://127.0.0.1/backend/api-vitoapp/verify-serial.php?serial=${serial}`).subscribe(data => {
    this.serialVerif = data.length;
    console.log(this.serialVerif);
    console.log(serial);
    })
  }
```

In my template, I have a form where the user can enter the serial number in question

```
<input formControlName="serialOKO" #oko (keyup)="serialVerification(oko.value)" (blur)="serialVerification(oko.value)"  matInput required>
            </mat-form-field>
            <span *ngIf="serialVerif == 0" >
              Device not found in database
            </span>
```

The problem is that the warning disappears only when the user leave the field, even the serial number is correct.
As you can see, I use blur and keyup for trying to do that but it's doesn't work like desidered.
Thank you in advance for your precious help

Comment: Use form controls. Then you have to make an asyncValidator doing your http call.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I new on Angular so I don't totally understand what I must do. Have you a little part of code for an exemple? Thank you in advance

Comment: you my find documentation about ReactiveForms.  You will learn how to make a FormGroup (your form), containing a FormControl (your input), and assigning a validator to your FormControl (which will be called everytime the value of the input changes). https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to make this.